# Search Communities By Tags

Tags: feature-request, search

On two recent occasions I have been unsure about which community I should post a question in.

1. The question concerned data handling/formatting in a statistical application. Should it go to *Cross Validated* or *Stack Overflow*?
2. The question is about highpass and lowpass filtering in electronic music using Pure Data. Should it go in *Cross Validated* or *Music: Practice and Theory*?

Before asking the questions I already have a good idea of what tags should be used for the questions.

I'd like to be able to provide these tags to the search engine and search across communities both (a) to find similar questions and (b) to get a better idea of which community it would be most appropriate to post the question in (e.g. via some sort of summary statistics).

Is there a way of doing this? If not, I think it would be a helpful feature.